# How to check the rowstate of grid grouping control in syncfusion using asp.net

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am trying to save the data from grid grouping control into database.This is the code I wrote in save button click event.

```
foreach (TableRow row in GridGroupingControl1.TopLevelTable.Rows)
{
    if (row is GridRow)
    {
        GridRow gridRow = row as GridRow;

        if (gridRow.Record != null)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee(Name, Dept, Desg) values('" + gridRow.Record.GetValue("(Name") + "','" + gridRow.Record.GetValue("Dept") + "','" + gridRow.Record.GetValue("Desg") + "')", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
}
```

For the first time I added 2 rows in grid and saved that 2 rows into database.Next time again I am trying to add 2 more rows into grid that time it is saving first 2 rows and last inserted rows.So how I can I find the rowstate so that last 2 rows which I added newly has to save in database.

Answer (score 0):

To update the database with newly added records, in GridDataSourceControlRowAddingEventHandler we can store the added records in ViewState and then in Save button click event we can insert the records from ViewState into database.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        this.GridGroupingControl1.DataSourceControlRowAdding += new GridDataSourceControlRowAddingEventHandler(GridGroupingControl1_DataSourceControlRowAdding);
    }

void GridGroupingControl1_DataSourceControlRowAdding(object sender,   GridDataSourceControlRowAddingEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Orders> records = new List<Orders>();
        if(ViewState["AddedRecord"] != null)
        {
            records = (List<Orders>)ViewState["AddedRecord"];
        }
        Orders obj = new Orders();
        obj.LastName = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
        obj.FirstName = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
        records.Add(obj);
        ViewState["AddedRecord"] = records;
        e.Cancel = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
private void SaveChanges()
    {
        if (ViewState["AddedRecord"] != null)
    {

        myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();
        List<Orders> records1 = new List<Orders>();
        records1 = (List<Orders>)ViewState["AddedRecord"];
        foreach (var temp in records1)
        {
            SqlCeCommand command1 = new SqlCeCommand();
            command1.Connection = myConnection;
            command1.CommandText="INSERT INTO Employees([Last Name], [First Name]) VALUES(@LastName,@FirstName)";

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", temp.LastName);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", temp.FirstName);

            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        ViewState["AddedRecord"] = null;
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    }
```